# Unexpected behavior using BSON: @load in Julia

Tags: julia

So, I am training a neural network model using `Flux` package in Julia. During training, each iteration that acquires an improvement in the model, the latter is saved in my computer.
For this, I use the line:

```
if acc_te[epoch_i] >= best_acc
     @info(" -> New best accuracy! Saving model out to mymodel.bson")
     @save "mymodel.bson" m
     best_acc = acc_te[epoch_i];
     last_improvement = epoch_i;
end
```

Which I assume is pretty standard (I extracted it from model-Zoo).

At the end of the training, it is fair to assume that the saved model "mymodel.bson" is the best I got. So far so good!.
Now, the problem:

Next morning, I open a terminal and this is what happens (every time is the same):

```
julia>using Flux;
julia>using BSON: @save
julia>using BSON: @load
julia> @load "mymodel.bson" model
ERROR: KeyError: key :model not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Symbol) at ./dict.jl:477
 [2] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/BSON/XAts7/src/BSON.jl:53
julia>
julia> #maybe try another name
julia> @load "mymodel.bson" someothername
ERROR: KeyError: key :someothername not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Symbol) at ./dict.jl:477
 [2] top-level scope at /home/gbrunini/.julia/packages/BSON/XAts7/src/BSON.jl:53
julia> #maybe try another name
.....same error...
julia> #maybe try another name
.... same error....
julia> #maybe try another name
.... same error....
julia> #maybe try another name
julia>@load "mymodel.bson" m     # eureca! this name works!
```

Why is this happening? Are there some forbidden names?
Sometimes it works with other names, but I always have to try at least 5-6 different names until I find someone that works! t's getting annoying

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and stay safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macros `BSON.@save` and `BSON.@load` store the variable with the exact given name. You cannot restore it under a different name.

```
using BSON
x=5
BSON.@save "mydoc.bson" x
```

This has stored the value `5` together with the name `x`.

If you try to recover it using wrong name it will not be found:

```
julia> BSON.@load "mydoc.bson" y
ERROR: KeyError: key :y not found
```

Rather than that - you need to recover with the original name - looks how the value gets overwritten:

```
julia> x=999
999

julia> BSON.@load "mydoc.bson" x

julia> x
5
```

So what to do when you need more flexibility? Use the `BSON.parse` function that returns a `Dict` and you can do with it whatever you need:

```
julia> BSON.parse("mydoc.bson")
Dict{Symbol,Any} with 1 entry:
  :x => 5
```

Comment: Thanks, @Przemyslaw I had no idea I had to load again using the same key name. Interesting. I was expecting more like a ```writedlm("savingname",A)```, ```B=readdlm("savingname")``` behavior. So, now I know which name to choose for loading the model properly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

## BSON uses Dicts to save and load

`BSON` does saving and loading based on a top-level `Dict`, which usually stores the variables by their name as their key (`m` in your case).

If you do the loading of your `.bson` you retrieve that dictionary and again instantiate the respective variables giving them their dict key as their name and their dict value as their value.

Taking a look at the `README.md` of [BSON.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/BSON.jl) showcases that already.

So in case you would want more flexibility you could directly save a `Dict` via BSON (check out the mentioned `README.md`) and do something like:

```
if acc_te[epoch_i] >= best_acc
     @info(" -> New best accuracy! Saving model out to mymodel.bson")
     bson("mymodel.bson", Dict(:model => m, <...other key-value stuff you want to save...>)
     best_acc = acc_te[epoch_i];
     last_improvement = epoch_i;
end
```

### Bonus / Opinion

BSON offers better interoperability between the languages, but when it comes to saving/loading performance and file size, I found [`Serialization`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/) doing a better job. So just in case you want to check out alternatives depending on your use case.

[edit: fixed typo]

Comment: Nice, thanks @Daniel I will make use of your suggestion to make the program more flexible!

Answer (score 0):

Since the BSON save the data as a dictionary, you can choose the `key` (keyname string) for the variable(s) you wish to save by supplying them explicitly (model->MNIST_model):

```
BSON.bson( "./models/MNISTmodel2023b.bson" , MNIST_model = model )
```

so the variable is 'model' which is save under the keyname `MNIST_model` which can be inspected

```
BSON.parse( "./models/MNISTmodel2023b.bson" )
->Dict{Symbol, Any} with 1 entry:
  :MNIST_model => Dict{Symbol, Any}(:tag=>"struct", :type=>Dict{Symbol, Any}(:t…
```

and now you can load it under the new name you provided

```
@load "./models/MNISTmodel2023b.bson" MNIST_model
```

and use it as so,

```
test_res = MNIST_model( xtest_batch )
```

If you forget the names of the keys for the file, you can always do

```
dict_bson = BSON.parse( "./models/MNISTmodel2023b.bson" )
string.( collect( keys( dict_bson ) ) )
1-element Vector{String}:
 "MNIST_model"
```